# NHibernate Cascade Insert when childrens already exist in database

Tags: c#, nhibernate, reference, parent, cascade

I'm currently working on a C# application that imports data from Excel sheets and inserts them in a database. To keep the data layer simple, I'm using NHibernate.

These are two classes I map to the database:

```
public class Bus
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Bustype Bustype { get; set; }
}

public class Bustype
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
}
```

I use cascading on the Bustype association in the Bus. My problem with this is, that Bus objects in different Excel sheets reference the same BusType. So I need to do something like this when I want to insert a new Bus:

- If BusType does not exist in database, insert it first, then insert Bus
- If BusType exists in database, reference existing BusType in Bus, then insert Bus

Is there any way I can setup NHibernate to automatically do this? Currently I have to check this manually, but I want to avoid this because it's a lot of extra effort:

```
if (busTypeRepository.GetById(b.BusType.Id) == null) {
                busTypeRepository.Insert(b.Bustype);
}

b.Bustype = busTypeRepo.GetById(b.Bustyp.Id);
busRepository.Insert(b);
```

Comment: What happens when you use `cascade-all`?

Comment: Does it work although I'm working with transient objects? (note: the ID of them is set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, that in this scenario your *custom* approach is simply correct, despite of your note:

> Currently I have to check this manually, but I want to avoid this because it's a lot of extra effort

The issue, why it could be hardly managed by NHiberante, is hidden in functionality NHibernate is offering to us, when working with *references* and their `Id`s (I.e: `Bustype` and `Bustype.Id`)

- either they do have `Id` a value == NHibernate expects such an object does exist, no need to INSERT
- the 'Id' is exactly equal to commonly expected "`unsaved-value`". We can configure, what is unsaved-value (null, -1, 0...) but we can have only **ONE value** representing the transient == unsaved instance.

Regardless of the fact that your question is about INSERT, this documeneted section *(please, if possible, read it carefully)* would give more understanding:

- [21.4. Using cascading Update()](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#example-parentchild-update)

#### Summary:

If objects coming from client *(e.g. Excel sheet)* do have the `Id` pre-set, regardless of the fact they are persisted or not, NHibernate needs our help ...